# Undefined method `paginate' for ShopifyAPI::Product:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, kaminari, shopify-app

I'm creating a web based rails application.
Can't find what causes the problem as mentioned above.

I have **gem 'shopify-kaminari', '~> 1.1'**

**I checked in rails console:**

`Kaminari::Helpers::HelperMethods.instance_methods`

```
=> [:paginate, :link_to_previous_page, :path_to_prev_page, :link_to_prev_page, :link_to_next_page, :path_to_next_page, :page_entries_info, :rel_next_prev_link_tags]
```

**gem list kaminari**

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
kaminari (1.0.1)
kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
kaminari-core (1.0.1)
shopify-kaminari (1.1.0)
```

In my rails controller, I simply have:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.paginate(per: 250, page: params[:page])
```

Other info:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.first => returns record (means ShopifyAPI request works fine)....
but implementing the pagination with gem 'shopify-kaminari'
returns the above error.
```

Anyone who has an idea about this?

Comment: Is this a rails api based app ?

Comment: @debasish117 no just a simple web based

Comment: i think including the Rails::Pagination module should work. And you can follow up this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45398116/rails-5-nomethod-error-undefined-method-paginate] . Hope it helps .

Comment: is that for api based ? but my app is not. i'm just simply rendering views

Comment: you have to use the paginate in view part right ? like this `<%= paginate(@products) %>` ?

Comment: yes, that's right in view

Comment: Guess you should use `ShopifyAPI::Product.all(per: 250, page: params[:page])` instead of `ShopifyAPI::Product.paginate(per: 250, page: params[:page])`

Comment: @debasish117 thanks, i found out that the gem I'm using updates the way of query. It's now like `ShopifyAPI::Product.all(params: {page: params[:page], limit: 5})`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ShopifyAPI::Product.paginate(per: 250, page: params[:page])` it should be `ShopifyAPI::Product.all(per: 250, page: params[:page])` and use `<%= paginate(@products) %>` in view .